# Is It Possible to Disable a Particular IE Add-on When Visiting My Site?

Tags: internet-explorer, ieaddon

I've been having a compatibility issue with the "Yontoo API" add-on from Yontoo LLC in Internet Explorer 9 (and probably 10). This is apparently a questionable add-on only available for IE (although it doesn't even register with IE) that deals with Facebook Layouts or something. Many users have reported that it registers as malware with their AV. I was just wondering if there was any way I could temporarily disable this add-on when users visit my site, via html/xhtml, php, javascript or any other method. Thanks in advance, hope you have the answers I want (as I'm fearing this might not be possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but the only thing to do would be to notify your users that this plugin causes problems and ask them to disable it. It's just not possible to disable add-ons programmatically.

Comment: Poo! Well I figured as much, but I just thought I'd get some confirmation. I'm sure you're right, but anyone else feel free to chime in if you know of any possible way. Thanks Abraham!